# Problem executing Google Cloud App using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've searched tons of posts but haven't been able to fix this problem at all for the whole day now...

I am trying to make a Google App Engine App in Standard mode and using Spring boot but I get the following error when I try to access the url that should work:

```
HTTP ERROR 503
Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.18.v20190429
```

I've followed [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/getting-started-with-google-app-engine-and-spring-boot-in-5-steps-2d0f8165c89) tutorial for my attempt...

I have tried to add Jetty as a dependency but doesn't work, resintalled Google SDK but doesn't work, removed tomcat servers but doesn't work too...

I've uploaded all the contains of my folder to [this repo](https://github.com/UlisesCeca/rrrrrr) incase it needs to be checked.

And this is my the log from running `mvn appengine:run`:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------------< com.cloud:demo >---------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:run (default-cli) > package @ demo >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ulises/demo/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ demo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests
19:59:53.452 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]
19:59:53.456 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
19:59:53.464 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
19:59:53.481 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
19:59:53.491 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
19:59:53.494 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/cloud/demo/DemoApplicationTests-context.xml] does not exist
19:59:53.494 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/cloud/demo/DemoApplicationTestsContext.groovy] does not exist
19:59:53.495 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
19:59:53.495 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]: DemoApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
19:59:53.528 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]
19:59:53.602 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/home/ulises/demo/target/classes/com/cloud/demo/DemoApplication.class]
19:59:53.603 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.cloud.demo.DemoApplication for test class com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests
19:59:53.685 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]: using defaults.
19:59:53.686 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
19:59:53.694 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition]
19:59:53.695 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttribute]
19:59:53.695 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@15eb5ee5, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@2145b572, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@39529185, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@72f926e6, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@3daa422a, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@31c88ec8, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@1cbbffcd, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@27ce24aa, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@481a996b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@3d51f06e]
19:59:53.696 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]
19:59:53.696 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]
19:59:53.697 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]
19:59:53.697 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]
19:59:53.698 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]
19:59:53.698 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]
19:59:53.701 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@72057ecf testClass = DemoApplicationTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1afd44cb testClass = DemoApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.cloud.demo.DemoApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@67205a84, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2a17b7b6, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@1e965684, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@4232c52b], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
19:59:53.701 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]
19:59:53.701 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests]
19:59:53.718 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=-1}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.1.11.RELEASE)

2019-12-28 19:59:53.939  INFO 19078 --- [           main] com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests      : Starting DemoApplicationTests on ulises-laptop with PID 19078 (started by ulises in /home/ulises/demo)
2019-12-28 19:59:53.942  INFO 19078 --- [           main] com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-12-28 19:59:55.052  INFO 19078 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-12-28 19:59:55.267  INFO 19078 --- [           main] com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests      : Started DemoApplicationTests in 1.542 seconds (JVM running for 2.143)
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.039 s - in com.cloud.demo.DemoApplicationTests
2019-12-28 19:59:55.422  INFO 19078 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.2.3:war (default-war) @ demo ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [demo] in [/home/ulises/demo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/ulises/demo/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [59 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/ulises/demo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.11.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ demo ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:run (default-cli) < package @ demo <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:run (default-cli) @ demo ---
Dec 28, 2019 7:59:57 PM com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk logCommand
INFO: submitting command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Duse_jetty9_runtime=true -D--enable_all_permissions=true -Dappengine.sdk.root=/home/ulises/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java -cp /home/ulises/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/lib/appengine-tools-api.jar com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain --allow_remote_shutdown --disable_update_check --no_java_agent /home/ulises/demo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 19:59:57.951:INFO::main: Logging initialized @415ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 19:59:57.994:WARN:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Ignoring deprecated socket close linger time
[INFO] GCLOUD: Dec 28, 2019 6:59:58 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader checkWorkingDirectory
[INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: Your working directory, (/home/ulises/demo) is not equal to your 
[INFO] GCLOUD: web application root (/home/ulises/demo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
[INFO] GCLOUD: You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server.
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 19:59:58.241:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.18.v20190429; built: 2019-04-29T20:42:08.989Z; git: e1bc35120a6617ee3df052294e433f3a25ce7097; jvm 1.8.0_201-b09
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 19:59:58.956:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=544ms
[INFO] GCLOUD: Dec 28, 2019 6:59:59 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] GCLOUD:   .   ____          _            __ _ _
[INFO] GCLOUD:  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
[INFO] GCLOUD: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
[INFO] GCLOUD:  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
[INFO] GCLOUD:   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
[INFO] GCLOUD:  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[INFO] GCLOUD:  :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.1.11.RELEASE)
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 18:59:59.579  INFO 19117 --- [           main] com.cloud.demo.ServletInitializer        : Starting ServletInitializer on ulises-laptop with PID 19117 (/home/ulises/demo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes started by ulises in /home/ulises/demo)
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 18:59:59.584  INFO 19117 --- [           main] com.cloud.demo.ServletInitializer        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[INFO] GCLOUD: Dec 28, 2019 7:00:00 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 19:00:00.347  INFO 19117 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 655 ms
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 19:00:00.817  INFO 19117 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 19:00:01.031  INFO 19117 --- [           main] com.cloud.demo.ServletInitializer        : Started ServletInitializer in 1.937 seconds (JVM running for 3.497)
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 20:00:01.050:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@7ce4de34{/,file:///home/ulises/demo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/ulises/demo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT}
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.isExported(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:70)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:64)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:347)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:343)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:283)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:271)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:44)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:220)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:218)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:218)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:404)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 20:00:01.052:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 20:00:01.052:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging disabled
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 20:00:01.058:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started NetworkTrafficSelectChannelConnector@2ac273d3{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:8080}
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2019-12-28 20:00:01.059:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @3525ms
[INFO] GCLOUD: Dec 28, 2019 7:00:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
[INFO] GCLOUD: Dec 28, 2019 7:00:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
[INFO] GCLOUD: Dec 28, 2019 8:00:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

As you can see there's an error in the logs which didn't help me when I searched about it too:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.isExported(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:70)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:64)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:347)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:343)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:283)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:271)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:44)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:220)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:218)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:218)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:404)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
```

If I execute the App with Spring boot maven plugin through `mvn spring-boot:run` it works perfectly.

If I also create an App Engine App in Eclipse using Google Coud tools plugin, the starter App that it generates also works with no problem. So it must be something wrong in my code or some configuration that I'm missing.

What could be going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've found the problem. Removing the Tomcat dependency wasn't enough:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I also had to exclude it from `spring-boot-starter-web` like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```